# KubeFlow End to End (Google Cloud)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a cluster following codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-kubeflow-e2e-gis/#1

But I am getting error when I run command `kfctl apply platform`:

> ERRO[0045] Updating kubeflow-qwiklab error: &{Code:RESOURCE_ERROR Location:/deployments/kubeflow-qwiklab/resources/kubeflow-qwiklab Message:{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/container-v1beta1:projects.locations.clusters"
>   ,"ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"No valid versions with the prefix \"1.11\" found.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://containe
>   r.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/qwiklabs-gcp-cb63974aba9fe7b6/locations/us-central1-a/clusters","httpMethod":"POST"}} ForceSendFields:[] NullFields:[]}  filename="gcp/gcp.go:278"
>   Error: couldn't apply KfApp:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: coordinator Apply failed for gcp:  (kubeflow.error): Code 400 with message: gcp apply could not update deployment manager Error could not upda
>   te cluster-kubeflow.yaml: Updating kubeflow-qwiklab error(400): BAD REQUEST
>   Usage:
>     kfctl apply [all(=default)|k8s|platform] [flags]
>   Flags:
>     -h, --help      help for apply
>     -V, --verbose   verbose output default is false
>   couldn't apply KfApp:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: coordinator Apply failed for gcp:  (kubeflow.error): Code 400 with message: gcp apply could not update deployment manager Error could not update clus
>   ter-kubeflow.yaml: Updating kubeflow-qwiklab error(400): BAD REQUEST

Answer (score 1):

Have received the same error following the GKE Kubeflow setup via kfctl.

https://github.com/kubeflow/examples/tree/master/videos/from_zero_to_kubeflow

Also uses the same version (v0.5.1).
Haven't dig in where the problem occurs but using the latest release (v0.6.2) solves this error for me. 
https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/releases/tag/v0.6.2